# String splitting in python in CSV columns

Tags: python, string, csv, split

So I am working with a CSV that has a many to one relationship and I have 2 problems I need assistance in solving. The first is that I have the string set up like

thisismystr=thisisanemail@addy.com,blah,blah,blah, startnewCSVcol

So I need to split the string twice, once on = and once on , as I am basically attempting to get the portion that is an e-mail address (thisisanemail@addy.com) so far I have figured out how to split the string on the = using something like this:

```
str = thisismystr=thisisanemail@addy.com,blah,blah,blah

print str.split("=")
```

Which returns this "thisisanemail@addy.com,blah,blah,blah"... however this leaves the ,blah,blah,blah portion to be removed... after a bit of research I am stumped as nothing explains how to remove from the middle, just the 1st part or the last part. Does anyone know how to do this?

For the 2nd part I need to do this from multiple line, so this is more of an advice question... is it best to plug this into a variable and loop through like (`i = 1 for i, #endofCSV do splitcmd`) or is there a more efficient manner to do this? I am more familiar with LUA and I am learning that the more I work with python the more it differs from LUA.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: @figs No, because if you were to look at the CSV in plain text the CSV would like like so:

"thisismystr=thisisanemail@addy.com,blah,blah,blah", thisisthenextCSVelement, 3rdCSVelement, etc.

So it would split the columns wrong, I would think, unless I converted it to tab delimited or something.

Comment: `split("=")` will return a list of two strings, 'thisismystr' and  'thisisanemail@addy.com,blah,blah,blah'. Run `split(",")` on the second string to get a list of strings that has 'thisisanemail@addy.com' as the first string in the list.

Comment: Ah, in that case can you make the delimiter different or swap the commas for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

myString = 'thisismystr=thisisanemail@addy.com,blah,blah,blah'

a = myString.split('=')
b = []
for i in a:
    b.extend(i.split(','))

print b
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the email out of strings in this format: `'thisismystr=thisisanemail@addy.com,blah,blah,blah'`

This is how you would do that:

```
str = 'thisismystr=thisisanemail@addy.com,blah,blah,blah'
email = str.split('=')[1].split(',')[0]
print email
```